# Screen Sharing keyboard issues

Tags: macos, mouse, screen-sharing

I regularly operate a Mac Mini (10.9.2) from my 13" MacBook (10.6.8) and edit audio and video using Audacity and iMovie. I just got a new(er) 13" MacBook Pro (10.11.3) and am trying to do the same tasks.

The issue is that while Screen Sharing from my MBP (10.11.3) my keystroke-mouse controls (ie: "⌘-wheel up" to zoom in) in Audacity don't work, while on my 13" (10.6.8) they work as if I'm sitting at the Mini itself.

Comment: I've about given up on an answer to this. The situation devolved to me screen sharing from my MBP to my 13" to the Mini. It actually works normally that way. The "solution" I've come up with is to open the document in the software in question directly on my MBP rather than screen sharing to the Mini. I still have to screen share for iMovie though, and hopefully it continues to behave.